# Heroku/Github set up connection issue?

Tags: github, heroku, hyperlink, connection

I am doing an exercise where I've a forked repository, and started a heroku account, did  "create a new app" and "deploy with github" but when I go to connect to github, a red error message pops up saying "Error: remote could not connect or was closed."

I have had no problems connecting github to other services, and I've found other people with connection issues, but more along the lines of "why isn't my app working" and mine is" why can't i link the two so I can continue with this exercise?"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've followed the instructions after setting up a heroku account, having an app repository fork on github, confirming my email, "create a new app" option on heroku, and on the ensuing "deploy" tab, clicked on the "connect github" option. I expected it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku and Github : Items could not be retrieved, Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892543/heroku-and-github-items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a known issue and caused by some data breach related to Github Authorization. Security measures have taken place and Github authorization has been disabled until further notice. Please see
https://github.blog/2022-04-15-security-alert-stolen-oauth-user-tokens/

And based on this ongoing [incident](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413),

> As reported yesterday, revocation of all OAuth tokens from the Heroku
> Dashboard GitHub integration is complete. Until further notice, we
> will not issue OAuth tokens from the Heroku Dashboard. These actions,
> based on our current understanding of the issue, should prevent
> unauthorized access to your GitHub repositories.
>
> We will continue to work with GitHub to provide additional guidance on
> how to review your GitHub logs for evidence of exfiltration or
> malicious activity. Please reach out to security@salesforce.com with
> any information that may assist us with our ongoing investigation.
> Please continue to visit status.heroku.com for the latest updates.

If you still want to deploy, you can switch from GitHub to Git quite easily, please read this: https://help.heroku.com/CKVOUPSY/how-to-switch-deployment-method-from-github-to-heroku-git-with-all-the-changes-app-code-available-in-a-github-repo